# Oracle: Partition table by month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, partitioning

My solution(months in german):

```
PARTITION BY LIST ((to_char(GEBURTSDATUM, 'Month'))) 
(  
  PARTITION p1 VALUES('JANUAR'),  
  PARTITION p2 VALUES('Februar'), 
  PARTITION p3 VALUES('MÄRZ'),  
  PARTITION p4 VALUES('APRIL'), 
  PARTITION p5 VALUES('MAI'),  
  PARTITION p6 VALUES('JUNI'), 
  PARTITION p7 VALUES('JULI'), 
  PARTITION p8 VALUES('AUGUST'),
  PARTITION p9 VALUES('SEPTEMBER'),
  PARTITION p10 VALUES('OKTOBER'), 
  PARTITION p11 VALUES('NOVEMBER'),
  PARTITION p12 VALUES('DEZEMBER') 
);
```

This doesn't work because of the `to_char` function.

Answer (score 3):

In 11g you can use function-based partitioning through defining a virtual column: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1.php#virtual_column_based_partitioning

Otherwise, you must manually define and maintain a separate column for the partitioning month.

I'd suggest using month numbers instead of names in either case.

Answer (score 1):

If the table  has a date column, the statement below can be used as an example for monthly partitioning starting from today (Oracle 11g):

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (date_column)
            INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'month') )
             (PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN ('16-MAY-2016'));
```

Comment: You need NUMTOYMINTERVAL if you want to partition by month, NUMTODSINTERVAL did not work.