# Partitioning by specific value and then by range in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I have a table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE CUST_HISTORY (
    ID          NUMBER,
    PRD_CNT     NUMBER,
    DATE_TO     DATE
)
```

Now, I would like to apply the following partitioning strategy:

- all values where DATE_TO = '9999-12-31' should be assigned to one partition called "p_max"
- all remaining values of DATE_TO should be partitioned by monthly intervals (from DATE_TO)

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858472/1509264):

```sql
CREATE TABLE CUST_HISTORY (
    ID          NUMBER,
    PRD_CNT     NUMBER,
    DATE_TO     DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (date_to)
  INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
  (PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN ( DATE '2019-01-01' ) );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=996361d05493565ddfc1342260be62f9)

If you particularly want the partition to be named as `p_max` then you can use a virtual column to remap the `DATE_TO` value from a high vale to a low value so you can name the partition and then use range intervals:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CUST_HISTORY (
    ID               NUMBER,
    PRD_CNT          NUMBER,
    DATE_TO          DATE CHECK ( DATE_TO >= DATE '1900-01-01' ),
    remapped_date_to DATE
                     GENERATED ALWAYS AS
                     ( CASE WHEN date_to = DATE '9999-12-31' THEN DATE '0001-01-01' ELSE date_to END )
                     VIRTUAL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (remapped_date_to)
  INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
  (PARTITION p_max VALUES LESS THAN ( DATE '1900-01-01' ) );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29a54bcc2ce922248ea327679bdbcce7)

or use `AUTOMATIC` `LIST` partitioning (Oracle 12c or later) with a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CUST_HISTORY (
    ID          NUMBER,
    PRD_CNT     NUMBER,
    DATE_TO     DATE,
    month_to    DATE
                -- INVISIBLE
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS
                ( CASE WHEN date_to = DATE '9999-12-31' THEN date_to ELSE TRUNC( date_to, 'MM' ) END )
                VIRTUAL
)
PARTITION BY LIST ( month_to ) AUTOMATIC
  ( PARTITION p_max VALUES ( DATE '9999-12-31' ) );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7f32e59f4bba9127b747c85f516d1ed)

*(If you want you can also make the virtual column `INVISIBLE`)*

Comment: Hi, this does not solve my problem. All values where DATE_TO = '9999-12-31' should be assigned to one partition called "p_max"

Comment: Hi, the second solution does not partition by month. Please see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c799df3776c7c9802aef5eca3299e66b

Comment: @kacperdominik Thanks, missed using `'MM'` as the 2nd argument for `TRUNC`. Fixed it now and updated the dbfiddles.

Comment: Thanks, but now the new values from SYSDATE (today 2019-11-04) are landing in the partition p_max, instead of being assigned to a new one, i.e. "2019-12-01". P_max should only contain records where date_to = '9999-12-31'.

Comment: @kacperdominik They don't appear to be doing so on the db<>fiddle - [option 2 - db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d43f7741caa7dc90753aab0655cd67a), [option 3 - db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc0da24d7f37a2a4d73111a2173eaa35).

Answer (score 0):

The solution with monthly partitioning (please observe `last_day` function):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CUST_HISTORY (
>     ID          NUMBER,
>     PRD_CNT     NUMBER,
>     DATE_TO     DATE,
>     month_to    DATE
>                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS
>                 ( CASE WHEN date_to = DATE '9999-12-31' THEN date_to ELSE TRUNC( last_day(date_to) ) END )
>                 VIRTUAL
> )
> PARTITION BY LIST ( month_to ) AUTOMATIC
>   ( PARTITION p_max VALUES ( DATE '9999-12-31' ) );
> ```

[DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aee0659908079a5cc41b1bc518f5e630)

Thank you for inspiration, [@mt0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0)!

Comment: This is fine but if you have `DATE '9999-12-01'` (or an other in that December)  then it will get put into the partition with `DATE '9999-12-31'` rather than into a separate partition. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=637dabbacfc44d1314784d11f742e060)